# How Can I Reduce Similarity Analysis of Multiple Time-Series Vectors into a Single Value?

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have ~15 independently-sourced vectors with about 1600 samples in each. They are basically continuous, ~1 Hz, from t=0 to 22 minutes. The nature of the dataset is such that the signals are definitely similar in some aspects, with peaks and troughs often occurring during the same periods, in response to stimuli.

How can I mathematically distill the similarity of all 15 vectors into one number? I'm relatively new to statistics, and I've seen the Pearson coefficient, cosine similarity, as well as some other methods but these seem mostly to be related to the comparison of exactly 2 vectors, and it seems it's not ideal to do all pairwise versions of these metrics. Can anyone point me in the right direction here, or give a summary of your recommended analysis? I'd prefer to implement in Python as the whole analysis pipeline thus far is built in it.

I'm attaching a raster plot of the data to help clarify, using matplotlib's pcolormesh so that the scale-minimum (0) is white, and the maximum (2) is scaled to black (rgb 255).

[image: raster plot of time-series data]

Edit: I trimmed the y-axis from the photo on purpose, in order to keep sensitive data anonymous, but it is the axis on which n=15

Comment: idea: calculate a mean of all those vectors and compute cosine similarity of them all to it? Calculating mean of 15x15/2 cosine similarities (*for me*) does not sound bad. And I should start with saying that you should ask this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @dankal444 ahh interesting suggestion, and yes sounds much better than an n! pairwise calculation. I'll give this a shot, but to be honest do need to wrap my head around whether this is statistically acceptible. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll repost there!